# Matching characters (inc. newlines) in a regex until next match is found

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to parse a log file using regex, the problem is as soon as I turn on SingleLine mode so that I can include multi-line errors then future matches are included in the first match rather than their own.

To explain better, here is an example of a log file:

> ERROR 16-08 11:09:59,015 - sdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
>
> ERROR 16-08 11:09:59,015 - sdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
>
> test
>
> ERROR 16-08 11:09:59,015 - sdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
>
> ERROR 16-08 11:09:59,015 - sdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
>
> INFO  16-08 11:09:59,015 - sdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
>
> test 2
>
> ERROR 16-08 11:09:59,015 - sdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
>
> ERROR 16-08 11:09:59,015 – sdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf

I am using the following regex:

```
.{5} \d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} - .+
```

This matches each line correctly but excludes the part of the message which has run onto a new line. But when I turn on singleline mode there is only one match (the first) and all the other entries are included in it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks :)

Comment: You want to include `INFO` also as part of the ERROR msg? It would be easier if you explicitly tell us what you wanna match and what you don't want. Also, paste the exact log file. WE can think of more delimiters from that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the idea behind this solution is to tell your regex not what to include but *where to stop*.

This regex uses a positive lookahead to stop nongreedily at the next occurrence of your regex (or at the end of the whole string)

```
.{5} \d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} - .+?
     (?=(.{5} \d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})|\z)
```

This includes also the INFO line as part of the previous error message. It sounds a little buggy, so, in case you want to consider the INFO line as a single error message (not part of the previous one) you might consider using this regexp instead

```
.{4,5} \d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} - .+?
(?=.{4,5} \d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})
```

Comment: I am not sure I get the different between the two regexes, both seem to be doing the job (I forgot to mention in the original question but the ERROR/INFO appears to be a fixed length of 5 followed by a space, so INFO is followed by two spaces). Also how do you tell the look ahead part to also match for the next log entry or the end of the log? As it isn't matching the last error

Comment: Looking into the first regex more, the \Z should allow matching the final log entry, even if I change \z to be 'end' and place 'end' at the end of the log file it doesn't pick it up?

Comment: This is a mistery to me too, from the tag I assume you are using .net, I'll do a bit of testing to understand. The matter for the INFO part is that in your example it has only one space after it. If you say that in the real problem it has two spaces then it's ok

Comment: Seems to be working now so going to mark this as answered, very confusing :S

Answer (score 1):

From your example text file it looks like there may be some blank lines. If that's ok, you should be able to use this regex:

```
^(?:ERROR) \d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} - (?:(?!ERROR|INFO)(?:[a-z0-9A-Z ,:\-\t]*)\n)+
```

If it was just a mistake and blank lines are not wanted, replace last `+` with `*`:

```
^(?:ERROR) \d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} - (?:(?!ERROR|INFO)(?:[a-z0-9A-Z ,:\-\t]*)\n)*
```

This won't match the `INFO` line, but you wrote that you want only errors.
If there are some other message formats (like `WARNING` perhaps), you must include them into this part: `(?!ERROR|INFO)`

Since you have no matching groups in your regexp, I used `(?:...)` non-matching variant.

Comment: Hi, you are correct, it was a mistake due to markdown, I want it to match ERROR/INFO etc, the only problem is that this doesn't match on the final line, is there a way of saying 'or the end of the string' as the final thing it should match on?

Comment: You're right, I forgot - if you change `\n` to `(?:\n|\Z)` (`\Z` being end of string) it should work.